# После НГ праздников ни один из компьютеров в локальной сети не может получить доступ к папкам любого другого

Tags: windows, администрирование, lan

Не сисадмин, но операцию по расшариванию папок проделывал сотни раз.
ОС Вин7 максимальная
Есть несколько компьютеров в локальной сети, подключенных между собой через сеть коммутаторов. И в свою очередь один из коммутаторов в цепи подключен к роутеру.
У всех компьютеров есть доступ к интернету.

Все компьютеры видят любой другой компьютер локальной сети, на одном из компьютеров, имелись папки к которым был общий доступ. Непонятно с чем связано, но доступ пропал.
Попробовал сделать доступ на всех компьютерах для определенной папки. Но бесполезно. Компьютеры в сети видны, но открыть друг друга не могут, как не могут и обнаружить подключенные принтеры.

Полный тупик, не знаю куда копать.

Пробовал отключать все коммутаторы от сети, перезагружал все компьютеры, включал один коммутатор и подключенные только к нему компьютеры. (предполагая что после того как кликнул по одному из компьютеров сети )

### Вот скрины:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

после клика на компьютер

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

если отключаю доступ с парольной защитой то могу открывать папки, а когда включаю просит авторизоваться. Ввожу логин пароль от пользователя и получаю такой сообщение

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `nmap` какие открытые порты видит на машинах?

Comment: @donRumata что это такое?) создал нового пользовталя с обычными правами дал ему право просмотра папки, и вот под этим пользователем могу открывать устройства и принтеры и папки

Comment: Сканер сетевой. На вике можешь почитать.

Comment: Может пароли менялись за это время?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение
Удаляй обновление KB4480970 , такая же тема была и после удаления все нормально.

Источник:
http://www.cyberforum.ru/windows7/thread2386536.html - решение